# Loop in 2d array with already 2 loop in java

Tags: java, arrays, 2d

I've got a problem, i do loop in 2d array in java but my instruction is in already in 2 loop for do different things.
Normally, it should happen like this :

```
public class stack {
private int tab[][] = new int[26][26];


  public static void main(String[] args){
      stack fen = new stack();
  }

public stack() {
    this.tab[0][5] = 2;
    for(int x = 0;x<25;x++) {
        for(int y=0;y<25;y++) {
        System.out.print(this.tab[y][x] + "  ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }   
}}
```

the console result : [ok](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rc2Zb.png)

but in my case i must use 2 loops for for other thing and with the 2 loop it's doesnt work at well. 
the code :

```
public class stack {
private int tab[][] = new int[26][26];

public static void main(String[] args) {
    stack fen = new stack();
}

public stack() {
    this.tab[0][5] = 2;
    int x1 = 0, y1 = 0;

    for (int y = 0; y < 910; y += 35) {
        for (int x = 0; x < 910; x += 35) {
            // Placer(this.tab[5][25], x, y);
            // Placer(this.tab[x1][y1], x, y);
            System.out.print(this.tab[y1][x1] + "  ");
        }
        System.out.println();
        x1++;
        y1++;
    }

}}
```

The console result : [not ok](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UST7Q.png)

I already try to put 2 loops to have 4 loops but it doesnt working.
So how to do loop in my tab[][] in my existing double loop ?

Thank's, Louis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you're updating your `x1` and `y1` at the same point, you don't increment `x1` in the right `for` loop.
Replace the two `for` loops with:

```
for (int y = 0; y < 910; y += 35) {
    for (int x = 0; x < 910; x += 35) {
        // Placer(this.tab[5][25], x, y);
        // Placer(this.tab[x1][y1], x, y);
        System.out.print(this.tab[y1][x1] + "  ");
        x1++;
    }
    System.out.println();
    x1=0;
    y1++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To add to Dirks answer, you can declare and update more than 1 variable in a for loop:

```
for (int y = 0, y1 = 0; y < 910; y += 35, y1++) {
    for (int x = 0, x1 = 0; x < 910; x += 35, x1++) {
        // Placer(this.tab[5][25], x, y);
        // Placer(this.tab[x1][y1], x, y);
        System.out.print(this.tab[y1][x1] + "  ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Comment: I didn't know that, nice addition!